# Clustered Index Seek and Non clustered Index seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I am using a SQL Server 2012 database and want to gain knowledge of query optimization.. doing that I came across one doubt and would appreciate if someone could please help me with that.

`Sales.OrderDetails` has two indexes : one clustered on `Orderid` and one non clustered on `Order id.`

First question: do we really need a non clustered index when we have a clustered index on `orderid`?

To resolve that I ran this query:

```
select orderid 
from Sales.OrderDetails 
where orderid = 10248
```

two times; one while non clustered index was enabled and other when it was disables. For the earlier version it did a non clustered index seek and for latter SQL Server performed clustered index seek. In actual there is no difference between the query cost.

So coming back to my question: do we really need to create non clustered indexes on the keys for which there is already one non clustered index and would that increase the performance?

Image1: [image]

Image2: [image]

Comment: If you have a clustered index on `OrderId`, another nonclustered index on the same column is **totally useless** - just drop it

Comment: You should not need two indexes on exactly the same columns.  The clustered index should be quite sufficient.

Comment: @marc_s : yes thats what is was thinking of.. but to confirm if I have clustered index on one column then i dont need a non clustered index on that right?

Comment: **YES** - that's **exactly** what I said in my first comment!

Comment: @marc_s : thanks.. appreciate your help

Comment: It can be useful to have a narrower index on `OrderId` in some circumstances. e.g. a query `SELECT OrderId FROM YourTable` might use significantly fewer reads scanning the NCI than the CI.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I was thinking about that, too - in the context of satisfying a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable`. But having the whole overhead of a separate NCI seems excessive; the actual querying (except for retrieving just the ID, which you typically pass in as a `WHERE` clause argument) will be satisfied by the clustered index just fine.

Comment: @marc_s yes, probably a rare workload where having both indexes would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

First question: When we have a cluster index on a field, don't need to non cluster index on that field.

Second question: In your query, you select only OrderId column and in this case not any different between non clustered index and clustered index. If you want to select another filed from Sales.OrderDetail table, certainly you see different in performance from clustered and non clustered index.